# Extract a value from the given data set in python

Tags: python

I am using below is my code and output

```
 test2 = json.loads(test)


[
{
    "cert": {
        "alternate_names": [
            "XXX",
            "YYY"
        ],
        "common_name": "aaa",
        "created_on": "1111",
        "status": "Expired",
        "subject": test,
        "valid_from": "2018-04-15T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "valid_to": "2020-04-14T23:59:59.0000000Z"
    },
    "meta": {
        
        "asset_name": "",
        "audience": "External",
        "automation_utility": "",
        "delegate_owner": "",
        "environment": dev
        "l2_group_email": null,
        "l3_group_email": null,
        "requestor_email": "",
        "support_email": "",
        "tech_delegate_email": null,
        "tech_owner_email": null
    }
}
  ]
```

I want to extract the status field and other fields from the data and append it to a pandas data frame as columns and export it to excel file .

```
 df['output']= df['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x:fetch_by_ser_no(x))
```

Now I want to create different columns for common_name,alternate_names,status etc .

being pretty new to python can some one please guide me through.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can try `status = test2[0]["status"]`

Comment: look here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: Not working getting this error  status = test2[0]["Status"]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I tried lot of things but it is not working. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part (extract the status field):

`test2` is a list containing one dictionary. This dictionary has two keys ( `"cert"` and `"keys"`). The value corresponding to `"cert"`is another dictionary that contains the key `"status"`. Therefore, you can access the status like this:

```
status = test2[0]["cert"]["status"]
```

For the other parts (pandas and excel) more information from your side is needed.